# SQL converting CSV text to Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv

I have a table with a list of customer orders (s84_Schedule). I have a second table with comments on the orders (s84_ScheduleNotes). When I pull the list of orders from s84_Schedule, I do a left outer join to get the latest comment from s84_ScheduleNotes, because there are not always comments on every order.

**Problem:** I also have a SQL function that converts a comma-separated list of ProductIDs into a temporary table; this function does not seem to be working properly. I do not understand how these are related, but... If I use only one Product ID (meaning, no comma in the ProductVal variable), the left outer join never pulls in the latest comment from s84_ScheduleNotes. However, if I provide 2 ProductIDs separated by commas in ProductVal, the latest comment will show up.

Here is the code that converts the CSV to a temp table (stole this off the internet somewhere a long time ago)...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Here is my procedure which pulls the orders and the comments...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetFilteredSchedule
(
  @InstallDateOperator INT,
  @InstallDateRange1 DATETIME,
  @InstallDateRange2 DATETIME,
  @InstallDateDynRange1 INT,
  @InstallDateDynRange2 INT,

  @CustExpectedOperator INT,
  @CustExpectedRange1 DATETIME,
  @CustExpectedRange2 DATETIME,
  @CustExpectedDynRange1 INT,
  @CustExpectedDynRange2 INT,

  @CompletedDateOperator INT,
  @CompletedDateRange1 DATETIME,
  @CompletedDateRange2 DATETIME,
  @CompletedDateDynRange1 INT,
  @CompletedDateDynRange2 INT,

  @ProdInStoreDateOperator INT,
  @ProdInStoreDateRange1 DATETIME,
  @ProdInStoreDateRange2 DATETIME,
  @ProdInStoreDateDynRange1 INT,
  @ProdInStoreDateDynRange2 INT,

  @InvoiceNumVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @InstallerVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @CustomerVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @SubdivisionVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @ProductVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @LotNumVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @EstimateNumVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @SONumVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @ProdInStoreVal BIT,
  @OrderProcessedVal BIT,
  @StatusVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @FieldRepVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @WorkOrderNumVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @WindowVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @StoreVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @DriverVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @YardEmployeeVal VARCHAR(2000),
  @TruckTypeVal VARCHAR(2000),

  @LotNumExact INT,
  @StatusIDExact INT,
  @SearchText VARCHAR(2000),

  @CustomerIdRestriction VARCHAR(2000),

  @OrderBy1 INT,
  @OrderBy2 INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT sch.ScheduleID, sch.InstallDate, sch.CustomerExpectedDate, sch.CompletedDate, sch.InvoiceNumber,
           sch.InstallerID, sch.CustomerID, sch.SubdivisionID, sch.ProductID, sch.LotNumber, sch.EstimateNumber, sch.SONumber,
           sch.ProductInStore, sch.ProductInStoreDate, sch.OrderProcessed, sch.HomeownerInfo, sch.StatusID, sch.FieldRepID,
           sch.WindowID, sch.StoreID, sch.ConnectedToProject, sch.DriverEmailAddress, sch.YardEmployeeEmailAddress, sch.TruckTypeID,
           installer.InstallerName AS 'InstallerName',
           customer.CustomerName AS 'CustomerName',
           subdivision.SubdivisionName AS 'SubdivisionName',
           product.ProductName AS 'ProductName',
           fieldRep.FieldRepName AS 'FieldRepName',
           window.WindowName AS 'WindowName',
           store.StoreName AS 'StoreName',
           stat.StatusName AS 'StatusName',
           driver.LastName AS 'DriverLastName', driver.FirstName AS 'DriverFirstName',
           yardEmployee.LastName AS 'YardEmployeeLastName', yardEmployee.FirstName AS 'YardEmployeeFirstName',
           truckType.TruckTypeName AS 'TruckTypeName',
           sch.ScheduleID AS id,
           Cast(customer.CustomerName AS VARCHAR(2000)) + ' - ' + Cast(sch.LotNumber AS VARCHAR(2000)) + ' - ' + Cast(subdivision.SubdivisionName AS VARCHAR(2000)) + ' - ' + Cast(product.ProductName AS VARCHAR(2000)) AS 'title',
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), sch.CustomerExpectedDate, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, sch.CustomerExpectedDate)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, sch.CustomerExpectedDate)), 2) AS 'start',
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DATEADD(hh, 1, sch.CustomerExpectedDate), 101) AS 'end',
           stat.StatusColor AS 'backgroundColor',
           note.NoteText AS 'NoteText'
    FROM s84_Schedule sch
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.s84_ScheduleNotes AS note ON note.ScheduleID = (SELECT MAX(n.ScheduleNoteID) FROM dbo.s84_ScheduleNotes n WHERE n.ScheduleID = sch.ScheduleID)
    JOIN dbo.s84_Installer AS installer ON sch.InstallerID = installer.InstallerID
    JOIN dbo.s84_Customer AS customer on sch.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID
    JOIN dbo.s84_Subdivision AS subdivision ON sch.SubdivisionID = subdivision.SubdivisionID
    JOIN dbo.s84_Product AS product ON sch.ProductID = product.ProductID
    JOIN dbo.s84_FieldRep AS fieldRep ON sch.FieldRepID = fieldRep.FieldRepID
    JOIN dbo.s84_Window AS window ON sch.WindowID = window.WindowID
    JOIN dbo.s84_Store AS store ON sch.StoreID = store.StoreID
    JOIN dbo.s84_Status AS stat ON sch.StatusID = stat.StatusID
    JOIN dbo.s84_TruckType AS truckType ON sch.TruckTypeID = truckType.TruckTypeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.s84_Employee AS driver ON ((@DriverVal IS NOT NULL) AND (driver.EmailAddress = @DriverVal))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.s84_Employee AS yardEmployee ON ((@YardEmployeeVal IS NOT NULL) AND (yardEmployee.EmailAddress = @YardEmployeeVal))
    WHERE
      (@InvoiceNumVal IS NULL OR (sch.InvoiceNumber LIKE '%' + @InvoiceNumVal + '%')) AND
      (@InstallerVal IS NULL OR (installer.InstallerID = @InstallerVal)) AND
      (@CustomerVal IS NULL OR (customer.CustomerName LIKE '%' + @CustomerVal + '%')) AND
      (@SubdivisionVal IS NULL OR (subdivision.SubdivisionName LIKE '%' + @SubdivisionVal + '%')) AND
      (@ProductVal IS NULL OR ( sch.ProductID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@ProductVal)) )) AND
      (@LotNumVal IS NULL OR (sch.LotNumber LIKE '%' + @LotNumVal + '%')) AND
      (@EstimateNumVal IS NULL OR (sch.EstimateNumber LIKE '%' + @EstimateNumVal + '%')) AND
      (@SONumVal IS NULL OR (sch.SONumber LIKE '%' + @SONumVal + '%')) AND
      (@ProdInStoreVal IS NULL OR (sch.ProductInStore = @ProdInStoreVal)) AND
      (@OrderProcessedVal IS NULL OR (sch.OrderProcessed = @OrderProcessedVal)) AND
      (@FieldRepVal IS NULL OR (fieldRep.FieldRepID = @FieldRepVal)) AND
      (@WorkOrderNumVal IS NULL OR (sch.ScheduleID LIKE '%' + @WorkOrderNumVal + '%')) AND
      (@WindowVal IS NULL OR (window.WindowName LIKE '%' + @WindowVal + '%')) AND
      (@StoreVal IS NULL OR (store.StoreName LIKE '%' + @StoreVal + '%')) AND
      (@DriverVal IS NULL OR ((driver.FirstName LIKE '%' + @DriverVal + '%') OR (driver.LastName LIKE '%' + @DriverVal + '%'))) AND
      (@YardEmployeeVal IS NULL OR ((yardEmployee.FirstName LIKE '%' + @YardEmployeeVal + '%') OR (yardEmployee.LastName LIKE '%' + @YardEmployeeVal + '%'))) AND
      (@TruckTypeVal IS NULL OR (truckType.TruckTypeName LIKE '%' + @TruckTypeVal  + '%')) AND
      (@LotNumExact IS NULL OR (sch.LotNumber = @LotNumExact)) AND
      (@StatusIDExact IS NULL OR (sch.StatusID = @StatusIDExact)) AND
      (@CustomerIdRestriction IS NULL OR ( sch.CustomerID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@CustomerIdRestriction)) )) AND

      (@StatusVal IS NULL OR
       ( sch.StatusID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@StatusVal)) OR
         (
           ('9999' IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@StatusVal)) ) AND 
           ( sch.StatusID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4')) AS X(id)) )
         )
       )
      ) AND

      (((@InstallDateOperator IS NULL) OR (@InstallDateOperator = 99)) OR
        (@InstallDateOperator = 1 AND sch.InstallDate = @InstallDateRange1) OR
        (@InstallDateOperator = 2 AND sch.InstallDate <= @InstallDateRange1) OR
        (@InstallDateOperator = 3 AND sch.InstallDate >= @InstallDateRange1) OR
        (@InstallDateOperator = 4 AND sch.InstallDate >= @InstallDateRange1 AND sch.InstallDate <= @InstallDateRange2) OR
        (@InstallDateOperator = 5 AND sch.InstallDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-@InstallDateDynRange1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm,@InstallDateDynRange2,GETDATE()))
      ) AND

      (((@CustExpectedOperator IS NULL) OR (@CustExpectedOperator = 99)) OR
        (@CustExpectedOperator = 1 AND sch.CustomerExpectedDate = @CustExpectedRange1) OR
        (@CustExpectedOperator = 2 AND sch.CustomerExpectedDate <= @CustExpectedRange1) OR
        (@CustExpectedOperator = 3 AND sch.CustomerExpectedDate >= @CustExpectedRange1) OR
        (@CustExpectedOperator = 4 AND sch.CustomerExpectedDate >= @CustExpectedRange1 AND sch.CustomerExpectedDate <= @CustExpectedRange2) OR
        (@CustExpectedOperator = 5 AND sch.CustomerExpectedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-@CustExpectedDynRange1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm,@CustExpectedDynRange2,GETDATE()))
      ) AND

      (((@CompletedDateOperator IS NULL) OR (@CompletedDateOperator = 99)) OR
        (@CompletedDateOperator = 1 AND sch.CompletedDate = @CompletedDateRange1) OR
        (@CompletedDateOperator = 2 AND sch.CompletedDate <= @CompletedDateRange1) OR
        (@CompletedDateOperator = 3 AND sch.CompletedDate >= @CompletedDateRange1) OR
        (@CompletedDateOperator = 4 AND sch.CompletedDate >= @CompletedDateRange1 AND sch.CompletedDate <= @CompletedDateRange2) OR
        (@CompletedDateOperator = 5 AND sch.CompletedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-@CompletedDateDynRange1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm,@CompletedDateDynRange2,GETDATE()))
      ) AND

      (((@ProdInStoreDateOperator IS NULL) OR (@ProdInStoreDateOperator = 99)) OR
        (@ProdInStoreDateOperator = 1 AND sch.ProductInStoreDate = @ProdInStoreDateRange1) OR
        (@ProdInStoreDateOperator = 2 AND sch.ProductInStoreDate <= @ProdInStoreDateRange1) OR
        (@ProdInStoreDateOperator = 3 AND sch.ProductInStoreDate >= @ProdInStoreDateRange1) OR
        (@ProdInStoreDateOperator = 4 AND sch.ProductInStoreDate >= @ProdInStoreDateRange1 AND sch.ProductInStoreDate <= @ProdInStoreDateRange2) OR
        (@ProdInStoreDateOperator = 5 AND sch.ProductInStoreDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-@ProdInStoreDateDynRange1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm,@ProdInStoreDateDynRange2,GETDATE()))
      ) AND

      ((@SearchText IS NULL) OR
      ( sch.InvoiceNumber LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        installer.InstallerName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        customer.CustomerName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        subdivision.SubdivisionName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        product.ProductName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        sch.LotNumber LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        sch.EstimateNumber LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        sch.SONumber LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        stat.StatusName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        fieldRep.FieldRepName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        sch.ScheduleID LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        window.WindowName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%' OR
        store.StoreName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
      ))
    ORDER BY
      CASE @OrderBy2
      WHEN 1 THEN sch.InstallDate
      WHEN 2 THEN sch.CustomerExpectedDate
      WHEN 3 THEN sch.CustomerExpectedDate
      WHEN 4 THEN sch.CompletedDate
      WHEN 5 THEN sch.InvoiceNumber
      WHEN 6 THEN installer.InstallerName
      WHEN 7 THEN customer.CustomerName
      WHEN 8 THEN subdivision.SubdivisionName
      WHEN 9 THEN product.ProductName
      WHEN 10 THEN sch.LotNumber
      WHEN 11 THEN sch.EstimateNumber
      WHEN 12 THEN sch.SONumber
      WHEN 13 THEN sch.ProductInStore
      WHEN 14 THEN sch.ProductInStoreDate
      WHEN 15 THEN sch.OrderProcessed
      WHEN 16 THEN stat.StatusName
      WHEN 17 THEN fieldRep.FieldRepName
      WHEN 18 THEN window.WindowName
      WHEN 19 THEN store.StoreName
      WHEN 20 THEN driver.LastName
      WHEN 21 THEN yardEmployee.LastName
      ELSE sch.CustomerExpectedDate
      END,
      CASE @OrderBy1
      WHEN 1 THEN sch.InstallDate
      WHEN 2 THEN sch.CustomerExpectedDate
      WHEN 3 THEN sch.CustomerExpectedDate
      WHEN 4 THEN sch.CompletedDate
      WHEN 5 THEN sch.InvoiceNumber
      WHEN 6 THEN installer.InstallerName
      WHEN 7 THEN customer.CustomerName
      WHEN 8 THEN subdivision.SubdivisionName
      WHEN 9 THEN product.ProductName
      WHEN 10 THEN sch.LotNumber
      WHEN 11 THEN sch.EstimateNumber
      WHEN 12 THEN sch.SONumber
      WHEN 13 THEN sch.ProductInStore
      WHEN 14 THEN sch.ProductInStoreDate
      WHEN 15 THEN sch.OrderProcessed
      WHEN 16 THEN stat.StatusName
      WHEN 17 THEN fieldRep.FieldRepName
      WHEN 18 THEN window.WindowName
      WHEN 19 THEN store.StoreName
      WHEN 20 THEN driver.LastName
      WHEN 21 THEN yardEmployee.LastName
      ELSE sch.CustomerExpectedDate
      END;
END;
GO
```

When I provide values to the dbo.GetFilteredSchedule Procedure, these are the vars I set...

- I set ProductVal to "26"
- I set StatusVal to "1,3,4,9999"
- I set OrderBy1 and OrderBy2 to "3"
- Everything else is NULL

Here's a print screen of what my table looks like...

[image: The table]

Comment: may I ask why dont you use SSIS?

Comment: After having posted my answer, I do think that your question is border line off-topic  due to luck of "the shortest code necessary to reproduce it [the error]" (see point 1 http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: OK. Thanks. Less code would be good, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.s84_ScheduleNotes AS note
    ON note.ScheduleID = (SELECT MAX(n.ScheduleNoteID) FROM dbo.s84_ScheduleNotes n WHERE n.ScheduleID = sch.ScheduleID)
```

I believe note.ScheduleID should be note.ScheduleNoteID

Comment: I do believe it is safe to say I love you. Thank you so much for sifting through all that code. As I mentioned, I will include only the necessary code next time. Also, I feel silly for missing this mistake in my code. But again, thank you so much.